# Проверить форму на ссылку.JQuery или JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Есть такая форма.

```
<textarea id="comments-form-comment" name="comment"></textarea>
<a onclick="comments.saveComment();return false;" >Отправить</a>
```

Как сделать проверку. Чтобы если в `textarea` есть ссылка или определенное слово *`(Например слово тест )`* пры клике на ссылку `Отправить` появлялось сообщение в окошке с предупреждением. И после этого чтобы отправки формы не происходило.

Вот полный код формы.

```
<form id="comments-form" name="comments-form" action="javascript:void(null);">
<textarea id="comments-form-comment" name="comment"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="jcomments.saveComment();return false;">Отправить</a>
</form>
```

Comment: у вас тэг `jquery` стоит с какой целью? При отправке формы получайте текст из `textarea`, ищите там слова или ссылки. В чем у вас загвоздка?

Comment: @teran я в jquery и js не селен. Поэтому как то не очень понимаю еще логику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведу общую логику как сделать поиск (jQuery)

```js
function saveComment() {
  var textarea = $('textarea#comments').val().indexOf('http://') > -1;
  if (textarea) {
    console.log('true');
  } else {
    console.log('false');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="comments" name="comment"></textarea>
<a onclick="saveComment();">Отправить</a>
```

Comment: С текстом понятно. А как hссылки отловить?

Comment: тоже самое, только проверяем например http, в ответе изменил

Comment: Хм, а `google.com/q` не ловит :)

Comment: @Arsen Спасибо большое, дальше уже как то прикручу сам.

Comment: @Other,  google.com/q это не ссылка (в понимании WEB)

Comment: @Анатолий, пожалуйста )), там так же можно поэксперементировать...

Comment: @Arsen, нууу... это как посмотреть. Особенно если `WEB` - это вообще непонятно что, да и ссылки не только в `WEB` бывают (fs, например).

Comment: @Arsen Мне достаточно этого, для меня главное было ссылки отловить и слова не хорошие. Это я такую защиту от спама хочу прикрутить в плагине Joomla.

Comment: @Arsen еще вопрос, как сюда добавить еще условия, делаю так  indexOf('http://','https://') на https не реагирует.

Comment: @Анатолий, `.search(/https?:\/\//i) !== -1`...